# Operation Denied while editing vgaswitcheroo

Tags: 18.04, radeon, vgaswitcheroo

I am getting Operation not Permitted error even if I am trying after login as root.

```
adnan@server:~$ sudo ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
[sudo] password for adnan: 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 27 10:12 /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

adnan@server:~$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
cat: /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch: Operation not permitted
```

[image: Enabling AMD Driver by vgaswitchroo]

Comment: That problem seems to be for all of the `/sys/kernel/debug` address space: I cannot write or read any file there on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with kernel 4.15.0-43-generic.

Answer (score 1):

One can try disabling "Secure Boot" in BIOS as suggested here:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397459